# Make a hash with two arrays, a Hash that has a key to array values

Tags: perl, hash

I have 2 arrays that I want to use to make a hash

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::MoreUtils;
use Tie::IxHash;    

my %KEY_VALUE;
tie %KEY_VALUE,'Tie::IxHash';

my @KEY= qw(
0
0
5
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
4
);

my @VALUE= qw(
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
);

@KEY_VALUE{@KEY}=@VALUE;

print join("\t",%KEY_VALUE);
```

The result that I get is:

```
0   B   5   C   1   F   2   J   3   K   4   L
```

This is because the value of the %KEY_VALUE keep updating as, it can only have 1 Key and 1 Value, in this case.

So, I would like to know if there is a method that I can save all the values with its corresponding keys.

Expected result:

```
0   A   B   5   C   1   D   E   F   2   G   H   I   J   3   K   4   L
```

Answer (score 5):

Just push the values to an array reference stored under each key. You can't output the structure directly, though.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Tie::IxHash;

tie my %key_value,'Tie::IxHash';

my @keys   = qw( 0 0 5 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 4 );
my @values = qw( A B C D E F G H I J K L );

push @{ $key_value{ $keys[$_] } }, $values[$_] for 0 .. $#keys;

print join ' ', map "$_ @{ $key_value{$_} }", keys %key_value;
```

Comment: I read document. However I couldn't understand this line `push @{ $key_value{ $keys[$_] } }, $values[$_] for 0 .. $#keys;`. Could you please..

Comment: @ssr1012: `$_` loops over the range of indices of the @keys and pushes each value into the array corresponding to the key at the same position.

Comment: @choroba, thank you, can I know for additional knowledge, can I sort the keys in ascending  numerical order? and can I also sort the values in ascending alphabetical manner for each keys.

Comment: @DanialHaris: Start a new question if you have a new question. Why are you using IxHash when you want different key order?

Comment: @choroba, because I thought, I need to match the values with its corresponding keys first, then I can sort it. If I sort it earlier, I scared the values and the keys is not tally with each other. Thank you for your suggestion to open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a hash where the values are arrayrefs holding all the values corresponding to a given key from those two arrays? Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tie::IxHash;
# Install from CPAN or your OS's package manager; not a core module
use List::MoreUtils qw/each_array/;

tie my %KEY_VALUE,'Tie::IxHash';    
my @KEY = qw(0 0 5 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 4);
my @VALUE = qw(A B C D E F G H I J K L);

my $ea = each_array @KEY, @VALUE;
while (my ($k, $v) = $ea->()) {
  push @{$KEY_VALUE{$k}}, $v;
}

while (my ($k, $av) = each %KEY_VALUE) {
  print "$k @$av ";
}
print "\n";
```